# How can I create a right aligned string with n digits from a number without the character for the sign?

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

I have integers in the range between 1 and 999 and want to create a right aligned string from them, without a space for the sign.

This is possible, for example with

```
select
   substr(to_char(theNumber, '999'), 2) as number3digits
from
   theTable;
```

The `substr(...,2)` removes the space that is provided for the sign. I am wondering if there is a still shorter way, without the need to use `substr` to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide sample data so I'm just wondering what's wrong with pure `TO_CHAR`?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select    1 from dual union all
  3     select  857 from dual union all
  4     select   34 from dual
  5    )
  6  select substr(to_char(col, '999'), 2) result_rn,
  7         lpad(col, 3, ' ') result_lf
  8  from test;

RESULT_RN       RESULT_LF
--------------- ---------------
  1               1
857             857
 34              34

SQL>
```

Comment: The pure `to_char(n, '999')` adds a leading space which is used for the minus sign for negative numbers, thus making the string four characters wide. I need exactly three characters, however (and my numbers are in the range 1 .. 999).

Comment: Does it mean that for -723 you'd want to get its absolute value, 723? That's exactly 3 characters. Or is it -72 (with trimmed last character)?

Comment: My numbers are in the range 1 .. 999, there is no -723.

Comment: Aha, OK. How about LPAD, then? See edited code.

Comment: LPAD will work, but it doesn't seem better than the OP's existing approach (using SUBSTR). I believe the OP was rather looking for a format model or model modifier (or combination of those) to achieve the desired result without the need for additional string manipulations. Alas I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @mathguy, I've checked **all** number format models available, checked quite a few of them and none helps. Therefore, yes - I also think that it isn't possible in a simple(r) manner.

Comment: @mathguy: that's right, I was looking for such a format model.